# Fetch month and Year Inside a List using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have list like this

```
 public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; } //smaple date 2014-03-31T12:30:03
}
List<Result>
```

I want to fetch all distinct month comes inside this list .
I have tried something like this

```
  List<string> monthNamesList = eventListResponse.result.Select(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.startDate).ToString("MMMM")).Distinct().ToList();
```

And it does the job, Only Problem is that if the list comtains two elements

```
2014-03-31T12:30:03
2013-03-31T12:30:03
```

My code will return only one month, where I want to get it like `2014 March` and `2013 March`.
So I created a new model class with year and month

```
 public class MonthYearMOdel
{
    public string month;
    public string year;
}
```

Can any one point out how I can fetch distinct months from my first list and store in `List<MonthYearMOdel>`. 
Where `2014 March` and `2013 March` both will be stored.

Comment: You didn't ask nearly the same question 20 minutes ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729192/fetch-months-inside-list-using-linq

Comment: @SonerGönül Read the both questions carefully, They are entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
List<MonthYearMOdel> monthNamesList = eventListResponse.result.Select(s => new
    {
        M = Convert.ToDateTime(s.startDate).ToString("MMMM"),
        Y = Convert.ToDateTime(s.startDate).ToString("yyyy")
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Select(u => new MonthYearMOdel()
        {
            month = u.M,
            year = u.Y,
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: { month = M, year = Y, } This line throws syntax error

Comment: it should be like this `{ month = u.M, year = u.Y, } `, i was updated the post

Comment: Now its new error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: ooohh, this `List<string> monthNamesList = eventListResponse.re...` must be changed to `List<MonthYearMOdel> monthNamesList = eventListResponse.re`, the post was updated

Answer (score 1):

Simple way (each string contains month and year):

```
List<string> monthNamesList = eventListResponse.result.Select(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.startDate).ToString("yyyy MMMM")).Distinct().ToList();
```

With `MonthYearModel`:

```
public class MonthYearModel
{
    public string month;
    public string year;

    public MonthYearModel(string dateTime)
    {
        var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
        this.month = date.ToString("MMMM");
        this.year = date.ToString("yyyy");
    }

    public bool Equals(object arg)
    {
        var model = arg as MonthYearModel;
        return (model != null) && model.month == this.month && model.year == this.year;
    }

    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (month.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ year.GetHashCode();
    }
}

List<MonthYearModel> = eventListResponse.result.Select(s => new MonthYearModel(s.startDate)).Distinct().ToList();
```